# Azure Synapse - Spark SQL Create Database Error: Hive IllegalArgumentException Null Parh

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I'm following Medallion Architecture. I already did the parquet files on bronze, delta files for silver, now I'm working on gold. When writing Spark SLQ (`%%sql`) to create a database I get a hive error `illegal argument exception null path`. This error is not clear enough what's going on in synapse? How can I debug this?

Code:

```
%%sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Gold;
```

Error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null path
```

I just need to create the delta database and tables for dimensions and facts.

Comment: I tested both with and without `LOCATION` as suggested in one solution, and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Gold LOCATION '<ADLS Gen2 path>';`?

[image]

Comment: I tested both with and without `LOCATION` and I got the same error.